Finite covering of Hirzebruch surfaces
Question
Let $F_n = \mathbb{P}(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}_1}\oplus\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}_1}(n))$ be an Hirzebruch surface and consider its finite covering(or double covering) $f: X \to F_n$.
Let $f$ be minimal, and its branch locus $B$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$.
1.
I would like to know the chern class of $F_n$. Actually, I want to calculate the chern class of $B$.
Consider the following standard exact sequence：
$$
0\to T_B\to T_{F_n}|_B\to N_{B/F_n}\to0,
$$
where the normal bundle $N_{B/F_n}=\mathscr{O}_B(d)$ ?(I'm not sure)
By Whitney’s formula, we have $c(B)=c(T_B)=\frac{c(T_{F_n}|_B)}{c(N_{B/F_n})}$.
Anyway, I want to get $c(B)$, and then I get $c_1(B), c_2(B)$.
2.
I want to know some properties of the canonical divisor of X, such as whether $K_X$ is ample?
I think this requires the help of this covering $f$ and $K_{F_n}$.
I'm not sure there's any other way.
Please give me some hints, or some references on calculating chern class through finite covering. I am very grateful.

What do you mean by saying that $f$ is minimal and $B$ has degree $d$?

@Sasha $f$ is minimal, which means that $B$ is reduced, here let $B$ be a hypersurface, and its degree is $d$

If you assume that $B$ is smooth, there is no need to assume that it is reduced. And you did not answer how do you define the degree.

@Sasha I think degree $d$ is the degree of the definition equation of the hypersurface. It is assumed here that $B$ is reduced and even irreducible in order to simplify the problem. Or there is no need to assume that it is reduced. I think it has no effect on the problem. The key is how to calculate its chern class.

The degree of a hypersurface is well defined when it is a hypersurface in a projective space. For the Hirzebruch surface, there are many different embeddings (and no canonical embedding) into a projective space, so the notion of degree is ambiguous.

@Sasha I see, then I am wrong here.
So if $B$ is a divisor, then how to solve this problem? suppose I already know the chern class of the Hirzebruch surface, and I want to use the standard tangent bundle sequence, but what is the normal bundle in the sequence.
Or is there any other way to calculate $c(B)$
